# Is it possible counting the records per hour in pl sql ? if possible please suggest query with simple example

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible counting the records per hour in postgres ? if possible please suggest query with simple example.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: You have to present a simple `CREATE TABLE`, sample data and a better description first.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple system tables that can be used for this purpose. e.g

```
select * from pg_stat_all_tables where schemaname='public';
select * from pg_stat_database;
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

For more details please see the following link:[MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS)